# About CPLEX files

Tags: cplex, opl

I would like to ask a few primitive questions about CPLEX:

There is a model, which is formerly written by someone else. Also, the .mod file is connected with a .dat file. Do I need to create a special OPL project area to use these files?

Do I need to open the .dat file with it?

Do I need to create and run a special configuration for it?

What are .ops or setting file used for? Why is it not involved in many projects?

I open and run these files directly (without opening the relevant .dat file and also without running configuration) from the file section and the result is obtained. Does it mean that I just need to open .dat and create a configuration while creating a new model myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you want to run within the IDE you need some run configuration. You may also use the command line oplrun.

See

[image: project OPL example]

.ops files are settings. They're optional

I recommend these videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hKPbl0vjQQ

and more links in:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/low-barrier-entry-optimization-through-cplex-alex-fleischer/

Comment: The link of LinkedIn has really updated information.